# Turing-recognizable languages are closed under intersection

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I know this has been asked and answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110500/the-intersection-of-two-turing-decidable-languages-is-turing-decidable) in Stack Overflow. I'm trying to come up with my own proof but I seem to have one small problem.

Basically, we have to prove that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are Turing-decidable then $L = L_1 \cap L_2$ is also Turing-decidable (a language is Turing-decidable iff a Turing machine exists which accepts all strings in that language and rejects all strings not in that language). We know that there must exist a Turing Machine for each $L_1$ and $L_2$, namely $M_1$ and $M_2$ which accept all strings in $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively, and reject all those strings in their complements. Using this I felt it very natural to come up with a new Turing Machine $M$ as follows:

[image]

The idea is that $M_1$ would reject all the strings not in $L_1$, $M_2$ rejects all the strings not in $L_2$, and if $M_1$ accepts a string, we then verify if $M_2$ accepts it, if it does then $M$ accepts the string. My question/problem is: **what happens if $M_1$ modifies the string?** Since a Turing machine can replace characters in a string this is definitely something that could happen, then what goes into $M_2$ will not be the same string as what went into $M_1$.

I thought we could avoid it by making another machine $N$ in between $M_1$ and $M_2$ that somehow reverts all the changes made by $M_1$ but I'm not sure how it would work.

P.S. I'm aware that I could prove this easily using the properties of closure under union and closure under complementation, but I would really like to give the machine explicitly which recognizes an intersection of languages.

Comment: A Turing machine with two tapes is as expressible as one. Using this fact just have two tapes, and turing machine N can copy the same input onto tape 1 and tape 2; pass tape 1 to $M_1$, tape 2 to $M_2$ - accept iff both accept.

Comment: Thank you very much, with that hint I am now able to solve the problem.